# How to access array inside array

Tags: php, arrays

I have something like this. I want to access "name" attribute. I can access it by

```
foreach($items as $item)
{echo $item->name}
```

I have tried
`echo $items[0]['name']` but it doesn't work.

```
    Array 
   ( 
      [0] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
               [term_id] => 7 
               [name] => Video/Animacija 
               [slug] => videoanimacija 
               [term_group] => 0 
               [term_taxonomy_id] => 7 
               [taxonomy] => portfolio_technologies 
               [description] => 
               [parent] => 0 
               [count] => 17 [filter] => raw 
         ) 
    )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the object syntax on `name` there as well.

```
echo $items[0]->name;
```

should work. Remember, you have the following structures

- an array (access via `[]`)
- an object (access via `->`)

Comment: I've never realized that [] and ->
Thank you :D

Answer (score 3):

`$item[0]` is a **std object**, and you cannot access to its value using **brackets**: **`[]`**, you should use  **arrow**: **`->`**

Like this :

```
$item[0]->name
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of objects, not an array of arrays. You need to do this:

```
$variable = $items[0]->name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an array inside an array, you have an object inside an array. You need to access it like:

```
echo $items[0]->name;
```